# Infopath shows error when I try to publish the blank form

Tags: infopath, form, forms-library

[image: I found this error]

I tried to publish the form with all controls using blank form to a sharepoint site. I created new form library and published. But it shows me the error as in screenshot("Infopath cannot save the following form. this document library was either renamed or deleted or network problems are preventing the file from being saved"). I even tried to publish the empty blank form to a sharepoint site, but it fails, again showing the error. Help me in this progress.

Comment: @teylyn can u guess what i am missing here

Answer (score 1):

Do the following three steps

- Add Windows Server Feature: User Interfaces and Infrastructure -> Desktop Experience
- Reboot
- Start Windows Services -> Themes service

To ensure, Review this link:

http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/21891/75649.aspx

Comment: Understand that this sequence of steps only matters if you are literally running InfoPath on the same server as SharePoint. If you are getting this error from a developer machine / desktop, these steps do not apply. These steps were just blindly copied into this question without actually taking the time to read the source material or ask any followup questions. (FYI, I do not know the answer to the problem if you are experiencing it from a desktop. I'm searching for that answer myself.)